# i am passing models to radiobutton, how can i make one as default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, defaultbutton, html.radiobuttonlist

passing a model to radiobutton which has three different values for example

<%: Html:RadioButtonListFor(model=>model.Country, Model.Countries, new {@class="countrytype"})%>

these countries has three values U.S,  Canada, Other. But i want U.S to be selected by default. How can my do that?

my actionresult is :

public ActionResult Select(CountryModel m) 
{ ... return View( new CountryModel ( countrytype.AsQuicklist()); 
}

how can i add model parameter in the return view?

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButtonListFor` is not a standard helper included in ASP.NET MVC. So the answer to this question will depend on where did you get this helper from and how it is implemented.

So a shot in the dark: you could try setting the corresponding model property in your controller action to the value of the button you want preselected:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    model.Country = "Canada";
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: my actionresult is :

public ActionResult Select(CountryModel m)
{
   ...
   return View( new CountryModel ( countrytype.AsQuicklist());

} 

how can i add model parameter in the return view?

Comment: @software, try like this: `var model = new CountryModel(countrytype.AsQuicklist()); model.Country = "Canada"; return View(model);`